# Server responds after 120s - how to find the hold up?

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I have a WordPress site that works fine on the front-end but the backend admin pages take just over 120s to load. The page doesn't timeout - the server responds - it just takes a long time. I see no errors in the PHP or apache logs.

Obviously the 120s is a clue - I'm thinking a CURL request or something similar.

I have used mod_status to look at the server-status - I can see one process that is held in the "W" state (sending reply) for the duration of the long page load.

Obviously the WordPress page process winds it's way through many PHP scripts - how do I find out where the hold up is happening?

I have tried brute force methods of disabling plugins one by one but with everything pared back I still see the issue.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Running netstat seems to confirm it's a curl like issue;

```
# netstat --tcp
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
tcp        0      0 myip:http                   12-34-56-78.dsl:56446       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      1 myip:35595                  87.65.43.21:http            SYN_SENT
```

The 1st entry is my IP making the page request, the 2nd entry is the server's IP - the request is not getting through the firewall. I don't control the firewall so I need to find where in the codebase this request is originating.

Comment: Have you tried to use [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) ?

Comment: do you have shell access to the server? you can check if there's any pending http requests (e.g. curl) by using `netstat`.

Comment: Thanks & +1 both. Marc B netstat seems to confirm that it's a http request at fault, but doesn't get me any closer to finding the point of issue. I will try to install xdebug and use profiling to pin things down.

Answer (score 0):

As is often he case the answer to this one was pretty simple in the end. Running netstat confirmed that a http request was the hold up, when I spotted it was a request to the server IP itself I realised it wasn't getting through the firewall. So I edited the hosts file with the domain of the WordPress site and the internal IP of the machine...

```
10.0.0.1    thewordpresssite.mydomain.com
```

Et viola the request can now be routed properly without falling foul of the firewall.

Thanks Marc B for the netstat tip.

Comment: you might want to accept this answer so question will be marked as answered...